# jQuery animate method won't start from current value

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm having a problem with an `.animate()` jQuery method.

Problem is, I have a `div` which current width is 0, when I try to animate it from 0 to X%, it doesn't go that way but goes from 100% to X%.

I also tried forcing the width before the animation and stopping all previous animations but nope, won't work.

This is my final command with all these attempts:

```
$("#div_3B").css({"width":"0"}).stop(true,true).animate({"width":"79.6%"}, 700);
```

Any idea of what could cause the problem?
I'll note that this single command is actually the last of a series of sequential commands:

```
$("#div_3B").animate({"width":"0"}, 700, function() {
$("#div_3A").animate({"width":"20%"}, 700, function() {
$("#div_3B").css({"width":"0"}).stop(true,true).animate({"width":"79.6%"}, 700)
;});});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the entire block of js (you have functions opening but not the closing), and any other css you have for the divs?

Comment: I put the parenthesys in evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the reason it's going backwards is because you're animating to 0 to start. Just put the width: 0 in the css, and then you only need the two:

```
$("#div_3A").animate({"width":"20%"}, 700, function() 
{
   $("#div_3B").css({"width":"0"}).stop(true,true).animate({"width":"79.6%"}, 700);
});
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/JmzjK/

If you DO want 3B to first go from 100% to 0, and then to 79.6 after 3A is done animating, then the code you have works:

http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/JmzjK/2/

Comment: I have nested animation cause I need to run them sequentially (each after the previous has ended).

If I run the three animations as 3 seprate commands, they just start at the same time. So I'm using the "complete" parameter of the function to set another animation to run after that one is ended.

Comment: Actually I was messing up while replacing the 3B content.

I replicated my final layout in your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/v2uHf/1/

It works. Thank you very much for your time.